# Store all the subarrays of a given array in an ArrayList of ArrayList and display the contents of the ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I want to store all the subarrays of a given array in an ArrayList of ArrayList and display the contents of the ArrayList. I have written the code for it and logically seems correct but I am not getting the correct output. Please help

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class ConsecutiveZerosAndOnes {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={1,2,3};
        //Find all the subarrays of the array
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>(5);
        ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>(5);
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=i;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                temp.clear();
                for(int k= i;k<=j;k++)
                {
                    System.out.print(a[k]);
                    temp.add(a[k]);
                }
                l.add(temp);
                System.out.println();
    
            }
        }
            for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < l.get(i).size(); j++) {
                    int tem=l.get(i).get(j);
                    System.out.print( tem+ " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you literally putting a reference to the same array(temp) in each element of the outer array. So you are filling it wrongly. I would recommend recreating temp instead of clearing, so you will have a separate subarray in each element of outer array.

Besides, you are filling it in a strange way, so when **i=1** you won't fill all elements of temp, I am not sure if this is what you want. Actually, you will add more than 5 elements to **l** which will probably cause an exception. So I would remove that **k**-loop.

Also, you create **l** with the size of 5 elements but in your loop, you limit filling with the size of **a**, which is 3. That looks odd, I would whether add more elements to **a** or set **l** and **temp** size to 3, or just not limit the size of ArrayLists.

So finally it should look like:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class ConsecutiveZerosAndOnes {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[]={1,2,3};
        //Find all the subarrays of the array
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> l = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
        {
            ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int j=0;j<a.length;j++)
            {
                    System.out.print(a[j]);
                    temp.add(a[j]);      
            }
            l.add(temp);
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < l.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < l.get(i).size(); j++) {
                int tem=l.get(i).get(j);
                System.out.print( tem+ " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }        
        }
    }
```

that should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting the expected output because your code puts the same `temp` object into the resultant `ArrayList`. That's why you are going to see N copies of the last sub-array produced by the outer `for` loop.

To fix this problem replace `temp.clear()` with `new`:

```
temp =  new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

**Note:** Currently your program produces all *suffix* sub-arrays, rather than all subarrays. If you need all sub-arrays, you'd have to add another nested loop to iterate over the last element that you are going to include for each initial element.

Answer (score 0):

```
class HelloWorld {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {-1, 2, -1, 3};
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
     
    for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++){
      
        for(int j=i; j<a.length; j++){
            
            ArrayList<Integer> ar=new ArrayList<>();
            for(int k=i;k<=j;k++){
                ar.add(a[k]);
               System.out.print(a[k]+" ");
            }
              list.add(ar);
              System.out.println();  
         }
          System.out.println();  
    }
    
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("---"+list.size()+"---");  
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(list);   
}}
```

****---Note---****

```
Above program will print and generate list of sub-arrays
```